# Flex Sprite ButtonMode

Tags: apache-flex, sprite

I have a sprite on which I have added two textfields
side by side, horizontally.

I have set the buttonmode of sprite = true.
But the mouse cursor changes from regular to
clickable only when I hover it on the textfields.

In the empty area between the two textfields,
the cursor still appears regular/normal.

Why could it be?

Answer (score 1):

The `TextField` instances are the only objects occupying space in the `Sprite`. Therefore, the hand cursor only appears when they are hovered. What you need to do is define the width and height of your `Sprite` to the maximum space occupied by your objects inside it (or greater than that, if you want), then apply `buttonMode = true`:

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mySprite.addChild(textField1);
mySprite.addChild(textField2);
mySprite.width = textField1.width + textField2.width + Math.abs(mySprite.textField2.x - mySprite.textField1.x);
mySprite.height = (textField1.height > textField2.height) ? textField1.height : textField2.height;
mySprite.buttonMode = true;
```

If that doesn't work, you can check out the documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Sprite.html#buttonMode

Comment: 1. Doesn't a Sprite adjust its width and height to fit its children?

2. I had tried to set Sprite's width and height manually, for e.g. 
sprite.width = 248 and sprite.height = 50, but strangely it stretches the textfields on it.